# Folium heatmapwithtime empty

Tags: python, heatmap, folium

I am not sure why the output is just an empty white space for HeatMapWithTime but the Heatmap is working fine. I used http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/HeatMapWithTime.ipynb as a reference point

```
df_cord2['weight'] = 1
cord_heat2 = df_cord2[['Lat','Long','weight']][0:100].values
date = df_cord2['date'][0:100]
print(date[:5]):

0   2018-11-17
1   2018-11-17
2   2018-11-17
3   2018-11-17
4   2018-11-17
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print(cord_heat2[:5]):
[[  34.1016 -118.3295    1.    ]
 [  33.7115 -118.2879    1.    ]
 [  34.0849 -118.3028    1.    ]
 [  33.8637 -118.2905    1.    ]
 [  34.0436 -118.2354    1.    ]]


LA_coord = (34.0522,-118.243683)

m2= folium.Map(location=LA_coord,tiles= "Stamen Terrain",zoom_start=11)

hm = plugins.HeatMapWithTime(cord_heat2,index=date,auto_play=True)
hm.add_to(m2)

m2
```

what am I missing here?

Edit: after many hours, finally figure out what's wrong. have to create a list type for cord_heat2

```
cord_heat2 =[cord_heat2.tolist()]
```